# Two-factor authentication problem on first attempt "You have sent too many codes to verify your phone number."

Tags: icloud, mail.app

I last signed in to iCloud weeks ago, got the code, and logged in. Recently, I got this warning that too many codes have been sent but I haven't even tried once. I've waited more than 8 hours according to the other post on this [subject](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/306022/505629).
Let me be very clear: I did not press to resend the code and I'm now locked. I even tried the code from weeks ago and that doesn't work.

[image: Screenshot of iCloud's error message 'Too many verification codes have been sent. Enter the last code you received or try again later.']

There is nothing I can do here

[image: Screenshot of iCloud's options upon clicking on 'Didn't get a verification code?' The options are 'Resend Code', 'Call Me', and 'More Options...']

I'm accessing iCloud from my browser, I no longer use an iPhone. What do I do?

Comment: Do you have a phone number? Texts or voice calls aren't limited to iPhones.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica ofcourse I do, this 65 are the last digits of that phone number, and the code I get is through that phone number. It isn't sending the code so the number doesn't do me much.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this anomaly, the way I solved it was by submitting an account recovery request (request to change my phone number). That process will take 2 weeks.

After the waiting period, I got an email with a go ahead to change my phone number within a week. However, the link from the email took me to a change password page which was confusing. I tried to login and this time apple was able to send a code to my old phone number. With that working, there was no longer a need to change the phone number. I made no login attempts for 3 weeks.